# Java RMI client side

Tags: java, interface, client, rmi

I'm trying to use the RMI Client-Server communication. 
I wrote the following class/interface:

1. Interface RemoteInterface extends Remote
2. Class HelloStub extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RemoteInterface
3. Class Server, which I binded the remote obj
4. Class Client as follow:

   ```
   import java.rmi.*;

   public class Client 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
       { 
            try
           {
           String globalName = "rmi//127.0.0.1:1099/hello";
           RemoteInterface remoteObj = (RemoteInterface)Naming.lookup(globalName);

           System.out.println(remoteObj.SayHello());


           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
   ```

I don't understand the reason why I must ude the interface RemoteInterface to do the lookup? Can't I use the HelloStub class, which is the real remote obj?

Thanks bye.

Comment: You have to use `RemoteInterface` to allow a level of abstraction - this way both sides (Client and Server) don't have to know anything about each other apart from the fact that both have to implement  `RemoteInterface`

Comment: Ask the opposite question. What benefit would you get from using the stub class? None. And what are you actually doing here? 'Calling methods on the remote object via the remote interface' is the answer. So write that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the class name, you can define Stub class instance instead of RemoteInterface and cast your lookup result to your stub.

But what benefit you will get defining stub insteadof Interface?